# Jquery and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying out http://materializecss.com/

When I look at their demo offered here:

http://materializecss.com/templates/starter-template/preview.html

I make the window small and it puts the links in a nav bar and shows an icon in the top left. When you click the icon it opens up the nav bar.

But when I download the source code that they offer here for the started template:

http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html

When I run the code my nav bar will not open....

the index.html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
  <title>Starter Template - Materialize</title>

  <!-- CSS  -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
  <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="light-blue lighten-1" role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper container"><a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#">Navbar Link</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Navbar Link</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="section no-pad-bot" id="index-banner">
    <div class="container">
      <br><br>
      <h1 class="header center orange-text">Starter Template</h1>
      <div class="row center">
        <h5 class="header col s12 light">A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="row center">
        <a href="http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html" id="download-button" class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light orange">Get Started</a>
      </div>
      <br><br>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="section">

      <!--   Icon Section   -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m4">
          <div class="icon-block">
            <h2 class="center light-blue-text"><i class="material-icons">flash_on</i></h2>
            <h5 class="center">Speeds up development</h5>

            <p class="light">We did most of the heavy lifting for you to provide a default stylings that incorporate our custom components. Additionally, we refined animations and transitions to provide a smoother experience for developers.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s12 m4">
          <div class="icon-block">
            <h2 class="center light-blue-text"><i class="material-icons">group</i></h2>
            <h5 class="center">User Experience Focused</h5>

            <p class="light">By utilizing elements and principles of Material Design, we were able to create a framework that incorporates components and animations that provide more feedback to users. Additionally, a single underlying responsive system across all platforms allow for a more unified user experience.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s12 m4">
          <div class="icon-block">
            <h2 class="center light-blue-text"><i class="material-icons">settings</i></h2>
            <h5 class="center">Easy to work with</h5>

            <p class="light">We have provided detailed documentation as well as specific code examples to help new users get started. We are also always open to feedback and can answer any questions a user may have about Materialize.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <br><br>

    <div class="section">

    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="page-footer orange">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col l6 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Company Bio</h5>
          <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">We are a team of college students working on this project like it's our full time job. Any amount would help support and continue development on this project and is greatly appreciated.</p>


        </div>
        <div class="col l3 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Settings</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col l3 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Connect</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-copyright">
      <div class="container">
      Made by <a class="orange-text text-lighten-3" href="http://materializecss.com">Materialize</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>


  <!--  Scripts-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../bin/materialize.js"></script>
  <script src="js/init.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

the init.js code is:

```
(function($){
  $(function(){

    $('.button-collapse').sideNav();

  }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
```

Comment: I also uploaded the code if you want to see it live:

http://beerportfolio.glass/test/

Comment: I just visited your site and the console throws errors. It seems that you didn't include the **materialize.js** in your site.

Comment: Check the logs in the browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

I created a `fiddle` for this is on working good

Try this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/abidkhanweb/s36xxxq3/3/

Answer (score -1):

Switch out

```
<script src="../../bin/materialize.js"></script>
```

for

```
<script src = 'http://materializecss.com/bin/materialize.js'></script>
```